# WSGI request and response wrappers for Python 3

Tags: python, request, python-3.x, response, wsgi

Are there WSGI request and response wrappers for Python 3?

[WebOb](http://pythonpaste.org/webob/) looks nice (although there is some [critique](http://devmeat.com/show/4986025)), but it seems to be written in [Python <3](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=533&show=all). Werkzeug seems also to be written in Python <3.

Should I write my own request and response wrappers for Python 3? Maybe this would be impossible, since WSGI seems to be somewhat [broken in Python 3](http://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2010/05/24/future-django-wsgi.html). So what to do? Give up Python 3 and go back to Python 2?

Comment: there is a replacement for wsgi in py3k, it's called [web3](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0444/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this hint! It seems to be a bad time, to write (WSGI) web applications with Python 3.

Comment: Web3 is not a replacement for WSGI, it is merely a proposal and pretty well guaranteed will not be accepted in it's current form and will see various modifications and still may not be accepted for anything.

Comment: I am not the author of WSGI. I am the author of mod_wsgi. They are two different things. One is a specification and one is an implementation of that specification. If you mean mod_wsgi then say mod_wsgi and not just WSGI as it causes confusion.

Comment: The `critque` link is broken. I would have liked to read it, and I can't find it on http://archive.org.

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation: right now, Python 2.x should be used for production quality stuff. I know, Python 3 is technically very interesting, but right now sticking with Python 2 is MUCH easier and MUCH more productive.

Answer (score 0):

No, there are not WSGI for Python3. It occurs because of new string types.